# Resample time series with duplicate values

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to resample a time series that contains duplicate values. I want to resample the time series to include a time point at every 0.1 seconds. For the new time points I'm hoping to insert  NaN values into these created rows and keep the existing rows as is.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d1 = ({   
    'Value' : ['A','A',np.nan,np.nan,'B','B','B'],
    'Other' : ['X','X',np.nan,np.nan,'X','X',np.nan],  
    'Col' : [np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],                          
    'Time' : ['2019-08-02 09:50:10.1','2019-08-02 09:50:10.2','2019-08-02 09:50:10.4','2019-08-02 09:50:10.7','2019-08-02 09:50:10.7','2019-08-02 09:50:10.7','2019-08-02 09:50:10.8'],
    'Count' : [1,1,np.nan,5,6,7,8],
    })

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data = d1)

df1['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Time'])

df1 = (df1.set_index(['Time', df1.groupby('Time').cumcount()])
        .unstack()
        .asfreq('0.1S', method ='pad')
        .stack()
        .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
        .sort_index()
        .reset_index())
```

Output:

```
                     Time Value Other  Col  Count
0 2019-08-02 09:50:10.100     A     X  NaN    1.0
1 2019-08-02 09:50:10.200     A     X  NaN    1.0
2 2019-08-02 09:50:10.300     A     X  NaN    1.0
3 2019-08-02 09:50:10.700   NaN   NaN  NaN    5.0
4 2019-08-02 09:50:10.700     B     X  NaN    6.0
5 2019-08-02 09:50:10.700     B     X  NaN    7.0
6 2019-08-02 09:50:10.800     B   NaN  NaN    8.0
```

Intended Output:

```
                     Time Value Other    Col  Count
0 2019-08-02 09:50:10.100     A     X    NaN    1.0
1 2019-08-02 09:50:10.200     A     X    NaN    1.0
2 2019-08-02 09:50:10.300     NaN   NaN  NaN    NaN
3 2019-08-02 09:50:10.400     NaN   NaN  NaN    NaN
4 2019-08-02 09:50:10.500     NaN   NaN  NaN    NaN
5 2019-08-02 09:50:10.600     NaN   NaN  NaN    NaN
6 2019-08-02 09:50:10.700     NaN   NaN  NaN    5.0
7 2019-08-02 09:50:10.700     B     X    NaN    6.0
8 2019-08-02 09:50:10.700     B     X    NaN    7.0
9 2019-08-02 09:50:10.800     B     NaN  NaN    8.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using:

```
df1 = (df1.set_index(['Time', df1.groupby('Time').cumcount()])
        .unstack()
        .asfreq('100ms', method ='pad')
        .stack()
        .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
        .sort_index()
        .reset_index())
dr = pd.date_range(df1['Time'].iloc[0], df1['Time'].iloc[-1], freq='100ms')
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Time': dr[~dr.isin(df1['Time'])]}, columns = df1.columns)
print(pd.concat([df1,df2]).sort_values('Time').reset_index(drop=True))
```

Output:

```
                     Time  Col  Count Other Value
0 2019-08-02 09:50:10.100  NaN    1.0     X     A
1 2019-08-02 09:50:10.200  NaN    1.0     X     A
2 2019-08-02 09:50:10.300  NaN    1.0     X     A
3 2019-08-02 09:50:10.400  NaN    NaN   NaN   NaN
4 2019-08-02 09:50:10.500  NaN    NaN   NaN   NaN
5 2019-08-02 09:50:10.600  NaN    NaN   NaN   NaN
6 2019-08-02 09:50:10.700  NaN    5.0   NaN   NaN
7 2019-08-02 09:50:10.700  NaN    6.0     X     B
8 2019-08-02 09:50:10.700  NaN    7.0     X     B
9 2019-08-02 09:50:10.800  NaN    8.0   NaN     B
```

As you see, I added the last three lines of code ^, I simply create a new data frame `df2`, which conditions the datetimes not in `df1`, and assign the rest of the columns to `NaN`, at the end, I concatenate the two data frames and sort it by the datetime then reset the index and there you go.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is `stack()` defaults to `dropna=True`. You can change it and do another boolean mask by `duplicated` after:

```
df1 = (df1.set_index(['Time', df1.groupby('Time').cumcount()])
        .unstack()
        .asfreq('0.1S', method ='pad')
        .stack(dropna=False) #change dropna to False
        .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
        .sort_index()
        .reset_index())

print (df1[~df1.duplicated(["Value","Other","Col","Time","Count"], keep=False)|~df1['Time'].duplicated(keep='first')])

                      Time Value Other  Col  Count
0  2019-08-02 09:50:10.100     A     X  NaN    1.0
3  2019-08-02 09:50:10.200     A     X  NaN    1.0
6  2019-08-02 09:50:10.300     A     X  NaN    1.0
9  2019-08-02 09:50:10.400   NaN   NaN  NaN    NaN
12 2019-08-02 09:50:10.500   NaN   NaN  NaN    NaN
15 2019-08-02 09:50:10.600   NaN   NaN  NaN    NaN
18 2019-08-02 09:50:10.700   NaN   NaN  NaN    5.0
19 2019-08-02 09:50:10.700     B     X  NaN    6.0
20 2019-08-02 09:50:10.700     B     X  NaN    7.0
21 2019-08-02 09:50:10.800     B   NaN  NaN    8.0
```